# How to upload 1 image to 2 different folder and resize it

Tags: php

I want to know how to upload one image to 2 different folders. Let me give you an example:

I want to upload 1 image. When I upload the image the system will resize the image to 2 different resolutions, portrait with resolution 400x400 and landscape with resolution 1200x1200. After the resizing, the resized image with resolution 400x400 will be stored in folder *portrait* and the other image will be stored in folder *landscape*. I'm still confused how to the make that logic.

```
<?php 

    //This is the directory where images will be saved 
    $target = "uploads/potrait/"; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
    $target2="uploads/landscape/";
    $target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

     //This gets all the other information from the form 
      $test=$_POST['test']; 
      $desc=$_POST['desc'];
      $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
      $loc=$_POST['location'];


     // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
     mysql_select_db("selfie") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

     $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']);
     //Writes the information to the database 
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO image_upload (category, description,image ,location)     VALUES     ('$test', '$desc','$pic','$loc')"); 


     //Writes the photo to the server 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
     { 

     copy($target, $target2);
     } 
     else { 

     //Gives and error if its not 
     echo "Sorry, upload failed."; 
     } 
      ?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! – [Jay Blanchard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard)

Comment: @ksealey I would expect a function called `move_...()` to actually _move_ the physical file. So that a second call would fail... Can you really successfully call that function _twice_? Or do you have to use 'copy' once?

Comment: so any suggest for resize the image to two different resolution guys? Please help guys

Comment: Stop using MySQL and start using `MySQLi`. Now.

Comment: @Martin or better: PDO

Comment: @Midas while PDO is indeed an equal or better alternative to MySQLi, for the OP who is still using Procedural MySQL, jumping to the syntax of PDO is usually a step too far and this puts many people off making the change. So I try to promote `MySQL --> MySQLi --> PDO` logic. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what an image resize function could look like:

```
function save_resized_image($file_in, $file_out, $new_w, $new_h)
{
    list($w, $h, $type) = getimagesize($file_in);

    switch ($type) {
        case IMG_JPG: $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_in); break;
        case IMG_GIF: $src = imagecreatefromgif ($file_in); break;
        case IMG_PNG: $src = imagecreatefrompng ($file_in); break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $w, $h);

    switch ($type) {
        case IMG_JPG: imagejpeg($tmp, $file_out); break;
        case IMG_GIF: imagegif ($tmp, $file_out); break;
        case IMG_PNG: imagepng ($tmp, $file_out); break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$basename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$tmp_name = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

save_resized_image($tmp_name, "portrait/$basename", 400, 400);
save_resized_image($tmp_name, "landscape/$basename", 1200, 1200);
```

This function doesn't handle image aspect ratio. But I leave this up to you.

**Note:** no `move_uploaded_file` is needed here.